# Check if element exists using interSectionObserver

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use IntersectionObserver to check when a div with ID of `cartTotal` exists.

I have a modal that pops up so the div doesn't exist until the modal is mounted.

I'm getting an error because of this: `Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

How can I get around this error by checking if the element exists or not?

```
 useEffect(() => {    
    let message = document.querySelector('#__next');

// INTERSECTION OBSERVER STUFF
const io = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => { console.log(entry)
  })
}, {
    threshold: [0]
});

// ELEMENTS TO OBSERVE
const blk1 = document.querySelector('#cartTotal') ? document.querySelector('#cartTotal') : ''

// START OBSERVING ELEMENTS
io.observe(blk1);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting threshold to 1.0, and adding the #cartTotal element to that same options object ,instead of after instantiating the IntersectionObserver? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: If I understand correctly, this modal has an id of `cartTotal` and you want to 'observe' when it pops up, right? Before the modal pops up, there is no element with id `cartTotal`, right?

Comment: correct @ParamaKar

Comment: @HeraldSmit i tried this but I get the same error because the div doesn't exist initially until the modal is loaded with the div

Comment: Then I think the more suitable option would be using the Mutation Observer API which checks for changes made in the DOM tree: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: When you start to observe ```io.observe(blk1)``` blk1 will be empty string if the ```cartTotal``` element doesn't yet exist, hence the error message. As @ParamaKar suggested mutation observer would be better for your requirement,